# Properties of P-matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two $n \times n$ matrices satisfying $0 \leq A \leq B$, where $\leq$ denotes element-by-element comparison. I'm trying to show that if $(I-B)^{-1}$ exists and all of its elements are non-negative, then $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists and all its elements are non-negative. Not sure where to start. I'm deliberately not assuming that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} B_{ij} < 1$, which would imply that $(I-B)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} B^k \geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A^k =  \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral radius of $B$ is necessarily $<1$.

Let $v$ be a Perron vector of $B$. As $(I-B)^{-1}$ is nonnegative, we have $0\le (I-B)^{-1}v=(1-\rho(B))^{-1}v$. Hence $(1-\rho(B))^{-1}\ge0$ and $\rho(B)<1$.

It follows that $\rho(A)\le\rho(B)<1$ and the Neumann series $I+A+A^2+\cdots$ converges to $(I-A)^{-1}$. Hence $(I-A)^{-1}$ is nonnegative.